# Could not load file or assembly WPFToolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, constructor, wpftoolkit

I am trying to use WPFToolkit in my user control dll. I inserted the WPFToolkit in its reference, and my user control dll builds with no error. 
Then I insert my user control dll into my application, but when my application new an object of my user control dll

```
  MultiROIStats mroi = new MultiROIStats();
```

the exception occured, saying:

**Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WPFToolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

Here is my user control dll code, the constructor where the error occurs.

View xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="MultiROIStats.MultiROIStats"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"    
             xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"              
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileData}" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
        <Button Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,4,0,0"
            Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48"
            Command="{Binding Path=GetDataCommand}">Button
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MultiROIStats
{
    using System.Windows;
    using ViewModel;

    //xmlns:dg="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WpfToolkit"
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MultiROIStats : Window
    {
        public MultiROIStats()
        {          
            InitializeComponent();    // exception occurs here!
            DataContext = new MultiROIStatsViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked the binary folder of my user control dll, the WPFToolkei.dll is there. So I am confused, and I am wondering how can I correct this error? Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue  is due  to that you are assining DataContext in your usercontrol's constructor. For a Time being please comment out that line. you might not get that issue.If u still have that issue then there might be other cause.

Comment: @AshokRathod Thanks. I have tried remove the DataContext line, but the problem is still there.

Comment: @Ono Could you resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you maybe tried the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit/) package for the toolkit to see if that works instead?

Comment: I can use the the same WPFToolkit in my other applications, and it was successful. I am wondering is the way I new the object right?

Comment: Actually datagrid doesn't seem to need the reference at all, I managed to use it in a sample app without adding the reference.public class DataGrid : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.MultiSelector
    Member of System.Windows.Controls

Summary:
Represents a control that displays data in a customizable grid.

Comment: and I think I am actually using that version.

Comment: DataGrid is within WPFToolkit.

Comment: Have you tried <DataGrid ... instead of <dg:DataGrid ...?

Comment: @NAJ installing the nuget package for WPFToolkit doesnt work.